# Wordpress showing archive.php instead page

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, archives

I have a problem with same name (slug) for category and page and wordpress is showing `archive.php` instead page custom template.

Permalinks settings for category is `.` and i want to stay this way but to force wordpress to use page on this url address.

Is there any way I can do that?

Category name is "example" so it's url looks like this: example.com/example/ and page name and slug is "example" so it's also example.com/example/
[image: FolderStructure1]
[image: FolderStructure2]

Comment: Do you have examples of the URLs for each as well as their slugs? This isn't the clearest at the moment and it's not clear if a precise answer is possible

Comment: Hello, i add example

Comment: and you have a `page.php`? But it loads `archive.php` instead? Why is your category permalink set to `.`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force WP then I would recommend to have a look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png)

One of the ways you could do it `page-$slug`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work - i change page template name to page-slug but wordpress still use archive.php

Comment: Just to be clear here,  could you tell me ,when you say archive.php, it's pulling taxonomy info or the post_type info?

Comment: This is archive of custom post type so probably post_type? Could You tell me how to check it?

Comment: You can do this by checking the body class, if you have the function [body_class]https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/ It will show you what type of archive it is

Comment: Sweet now we know what page it is. Since it's post type archive and you want to show the the page template instead of  could can disable the archive feature of the post type by setting `has_archive ` as false where you registered the custom post type

Comment: Great! But now it's showing archive category so still no page template

Comment: That's odd. Could you add your theme's folder and structure screen shot

Comment: Hello, photo list of files added :)

Comment: I tried using `.` for permalink settings for category. 
1. I am getting a 404 error even after I reset the permalinks

I created a category called `test` and a page with slug `test` as well  with permalinks for category as `.` and a page template called `page-test.php`

WordPress is going with `page-test.php` instead of the category. I am guessing you might have a spell check error?